# Zendesk Chat API with Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, zendesk

I am working on a project that requires me to add zendesk chat to an existing nativescript mobile app.
Since there is no plugin available for Chat (just Support), I am assuming that will have to use the native libraries available for both platforms.  I was reading the NS documentation on the topic, but I am having trouble applying it to this particular scenario.

Does anyone have experience with integrating the Chat API with an NS mobile app?  If so, I would really appreciate it if you provide some guidance on how to get started.

Thank you

Comment: I started with iOS and I tried copying the Zendesk iOS SDK files to the platform/ios folder, but from there I am really not sure how to proceed.  Is that enough to make it available to my TS code?  How do I import it to my TS file, etc

Comment: @mast3rd3mon: Did you have any useful suggestion or just downvoted the question because I did not include 'what I have tried' portion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I found this plugin:  https://github.com/qlehong/Zendesk-Chat-Nativescript

Even though the documentation does not include the Chat functionality, looking at the source code I found the openChat function.  So, you can start the chat by running:

```js
var zdClient = require('nativescript-zendesk-with-chat');

...

let zd = zdClient.initChat({
  accountKey: '<your key here>'
});

zd.openChat({
  name: '<the user's name>',
  email: '<the user's email>'
});
```

I know this does not exactly answer the original question, but it accomplishes the task of integrating the Chat SDK with the NS app.

Hope this saves someone some research time.